# Copy specific text between -> <-

Tags: mirc

I'm now using this code to copy a section in the text. 
I want to change the code so that it copys the whole text between 2 tags.

**Example** 
-> this text copy <- (copy just between -> and <-)

The code now is

```
ON *:TEXT:*->*:*: {
  if ($nick == Nickname) {
    /msg $chan $$9
  }
}
```

This wil just copy the 9th, now i want it to get $- all text between -> <-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your current msg command, try the following command:

```
msg $chan $mid($1-, $calc($pos($1-, ->, 1) + 2), $calc($pos($1-, <-, $pos($1-, <-, 0)) - $pos($1-, ->, 1) - 2))
```

This line will take the first occurrence of -> and last occurence of <-, and message everything that's between them.